# Find the text of a li inside a div which has no unique attributes using Watir

Tags: watir

I am trying to get a text value from a li which is a child items of a div. My problem is that there are more than one div with the same class name. Watir considers the first div alone. I tried the following:

```
ie.div(:class,'class1', :index => 0).lis.each do |li|
  puts li.text
end
```

I changed the indexes but it just prints out nothing

Process finished with exit code 0

Please let me know if there is way to extract "Order Number: 12345678".

HTML code:

```
<html>
 <body>
  <form name:"Form1" action="action.cfm">
   <table width = "100%" align = "center" cellPadding = "10">
     <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="33%" vAlign="top">
      <td width="33%" vAlign="top">
      <td width="33%" vAlign="top">
       <div class="class1">
       <div class="class2">
       <div class="class3">
       <div class="class4">
       <div class="class5">
       <div class="class4">
       <div class="class2">
       <div class="class1">
           <li>
          Text - Order Number: 12345678
      <td width="33%" vAlign="top">
        .
        .
        .
      <td width="33%" vAlign="top">
```

Thank you!

Comment: Changing `:index => 0` to `:index => 1` should return the text, but--long term--that's likely going to be a fragile solution.

Comment: How do you as a person know which text to get? There must be more to the page or do you just look for the text Order Number? Either way it would help to give a more complete html sample. It seems a bit unlikely that the li element is nested within several divs of the same class. Remember that a question like this needs a good html sample to get a useful answer.

Comment: @Justin Ko The Html is of the same structure that is above there, I had just changed the class names. The order number(s) is generated at this order confirmation page and it is nested in a table as a bullet point. This bullet item(li) is a child of a div. However there are 2 Divs with  exact properties except for the text that they contain. I hope there is some way to differentiate the divs with text that they contain and then derive the text of the li.

Comment: ` <html>
 <body>
  <form name:"Form1" action="action.cfm">
   <table width = "100%" align = "center" cellPadding = "10">
     <tbody>
 <tr>
   <td width="33%" vAlign="top">
   <td width="33%" vAlign="top">
   <td width="33%" vAlign="top">
    <div class="class1">
  Text - Application Information
    <div class="class2">
    <div class="class3">
    <div class="class4">
    <div class="class5">
    <div class="class4">
    <div class="class2">
    <div class="class1">
        <li>
    Text - Order Number: 12345678
   <td width="33%" vAlign="top">
  .
   <td width="33%" vAlign="top">  `

Comment: There are no closing tags anywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that "Order Number" is a known text, you can use it to locate the desired element.

If "Order Number" only appears once in a list item, I would suggest bypassing the div and getting the li directly:

```
browser.li(:text => /Order Number:/).text
#=> "Order Number: 12345678"
```

If you need the div element, you could get it by its class and text:

```
parent_div = browser.div(:class => 'class1', :text => /Order Number:/)
parent_div.li.text
#=> "Order Number: 12345678"
```

Note that we are using a regex to match the text as it allows for partial matches (ie in comparison to using a string which is an exact match).

Comment: This solution worked for me!   Thank you so much guys!         browser.li(:text => /Order Number:/).text
#=> "Order Number: 12345678"